# Update two components no relationship Ruby on Rails & ReactJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, reactjs, components

I have a working app using Ruby on Rails and ReactJS which has four components:

1. ProductContainer
2. ProductItem (child of ProductContainer)
3. BasketContainer
4. BasketItem (child of BasketContainer)

At the moment I use Ajax calls to create new Basket Items when a 'Add to Basket' button is clicked in my Product Items Component. This works fine but the state is not updating without a page refresh and I am unsure how to alert BasketContainer/BasketItem that it needs to re-render the component.

I believe I need to setState on the success of my Ajax call but am unsure how to do this for another component. Any advice would be much appreciated.

**ProductItem Component**

```
class ProductItem extends React.Component{

constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = { 
        name: '',
        price: 0,
        code: '',
        id: ''
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        name: this.props.data.name,
        price: this.props.data.price,
        code: this.props.data.code,
        id: this.props.data.id
    })
}

addtoBasket() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/items",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            item: {
                name: this.state.name,
                price: this.state.price,
                code: this.state.code
            }
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    })
}

render(){
    let productName = this.props.data.name
    let productPrice = this.props.data.price
    let productCode = this.props.data.code
    let productImg = this.props.data.image_url

    return (
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 product">
            <img src={productImg}/>
            <h3 className="text-center">{productName}</h3>
            <h5 className="text-center">£{productPrice}</h5>
            <div className="text-center">
                <button onClick={this.addtoBasket.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Add to Basket</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

**BasketItem Component**

```
class BasketItem extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super()

    this.state = { 
        name: '',
        price: 0,
        code: '',
        id: '',
        quantity: 1,
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        name: this.props.data.name,
        price: this.props.data.price,
        code: this.props.data.code,
        id: this.props.data.id,
    })
}

deleteItem() {
    let finalUrl = '/items/' + this.state.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: finalUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("successfully deleted");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    })
}   


render(){
    let itemName = this.props.data.name
    let itemCode = this.props.data.code
    let itemQuantity = 1
    let itemPrice = (this.props.data.price * itemQuantity).toFixed(2)
    const itemId = this.props.data.id

    return(
        <tr>
            <td>{itemName}</td>
            <td>{itemCode}</td>
            <td>{itemQuantity}</td>
            <td><button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this)}>Remove</button></td>
            <td>£{itemPrice}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

}

**ProductContainer Component**

```
class ProductContainer extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        products: []
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState( {
        products: this.props.products
    })
}

render(){
    let p = this.state.products

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Products</h1>
            <div className="row">
                {p.map(function(product){
                    return <ProductItem data={product} key={product.id} />;
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

**BasketContainer Component**

```
class BasketContainer extends React.Component{

constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        items: [],
        subTotal: 0,
        totalPrice: 0,
        deliveryPrice: 0
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState( {
        items: this.props.items,
    })
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.calculateTotals();
}

calculateTotals() {
    let subtotal = this.state.subTotal
    let delivery = this.state.deliveryPrice

    for (var i=0; i<this.state.items.length; i++) {
        subtotal += Number(this.state.items[i].price);
    }

    if (subtotal > 90) {
        delivery = 0;
    } else if (subtotal >= 50 & subtotal < 90 ) {
        delivery = 2.95;
    } else {
        delivery = 4.95;
    }

    this.setState( {
        deliveryPrice: delivery,
        subTotal: subtotal,
        totalPrice: subtotal + delivery
    })
}

render(){

    const {
        totalPrice,
        subTotal,
        deliveryPrice
    } = this.state;

    let i = this.state.items
    let basketBlock;
    let basketCount;
    let basketSubtotal;
    let basketDelivery;
    let basketTotal;

    if (i) {

        if (i.length === 1) {
            basketCount = (
                <span className="basket-count">
                    ({i.length} item)
                </span>
            )
        } else {
            basketCount = (
                <span className="basket-count">
                    ({i.length} items)
                </span>
            )
        }

        basketSubtotal = (
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
                <td>£{subTotal.toFixed(2)}</td>
            </tr>
        )
        basketDelivery = (
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <th>Delivery</th>
                <td>£{deliveryPrice.toFixed(2)}</td>
            </tr>
        )
        basketTotal = (
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <th>Total</th>
                <td>£{totalPrice.toFixed(2)}</td>
            </tr>
        )
        basketBlock = (
            <div className="col-xs-12">
                <div className="well">
                    <table className="table table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th>Code</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {i.map(function(item){
                                return <BasketItem data={item} key={item.id} />;
                            })}
                            {basketSubtotal}
                            {basketDelivery}
                            {basketTotal}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )

    } else {

        basketCount = (
            <span className="basket-count">
                pluralize(0 Items)
            </span>
        )
        basketBlock = (
            <div className="col-xs-12">
                <div className="well">
                    <h5>Add an item</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Basket {basketCount}</h1>
            <div className="row">
                {basketBlock}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

**Pages Index - where the components are mounted into the view**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
        <%= react_component('ProductContainer', render( template: 'products/index.json.jbuilder')) %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 basket">
        <%= react_component 'BasketContainer', render( template: 'items/index.json.jbuilder') %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the callback method from your parents component to child and update the parent on success of your child's ajax call success.

Example

```
    //Parent component

    handleCallback: function(data) {
        // refresh the list
    },
    <somecomponent onSuccess={this.handlecallback} /> //call to child component

   // Child Component

   ajax.success(){
    this.props.onSuccess(datafromresult);
   }
```

That should resolve your problem :)

Comment: Hey Amit, thanks for your response again. :) Which Child and parent components are you referring to?

Comment: The component which you want to update will be the component that you have children. So its simple. In ur case BasketContainer Component is the parent and BasketItem is child. :)

Comment: I don't think this will work as the Add to basket button is in the ProductItem Component and then the HandleCallback function would be in the BasketContainer component. In rails these are added into the view separately and so there doesn't seem to be a relationship between them. I'll add the view to the question so you can see what I mean :)